# Play random sounds from my projects in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm new in iOS. I have written this code, which plays only one audio file when tapping a UIButton. I would like to play multiple sound randomly. How to set it? Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
           if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "kompilacja", withExtension: "mp3") {

                do {
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                audioPlayer.play()
            }else{
                print("Karwasz twarz! Brak pliku audio, Panie!")
            }
        }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all of your sound file names in an array and use the randomElement method to choose your sound.

```
@IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let sounds = ["kompilacja", "another sound", "yet another sound"]
    guard let sound = sounds.randomElement(),
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sound, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to play one random sound. He wants to **play multiple sound randomly**